# Spring integration test: How to use @Sql with dynamic schema name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I am looking at using @Sql in my integration test for cleaning up data before a test case. Annotation solves the use case that I have.

The only caveat is I am not able to figure out on passing the schema name, which is different for me in each environment.

```
 @Test
  @Sql({"classpath:sql/clean_up_script.sql"})
  public void testEntireJob() throws Exception {

   //test case

  }
}
```

clean_up_script.sql

```
truncate table schema_name.sample;
```

In SQL, I don't want to hardcode the schema name. Is there a way, I can pass the parameter which is taken as a schema name.

P.S I am using flyway for DB migration but this script is not part of the flyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a `application.properties` file inside `src/test/resources` and specify the schema for the whole test execution with: (assuming you use `@SpringBootTest` to start the whole Spring context for your test):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema
```

There is also an annotation available to *inline* this config: `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema")`

You can also specify the name of the schema as part of the JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=my:schema
```

With this approach your `.sql` files can be schema-free and the configuration is at a central place.

Comment: Just to add that you can even define different profiles, create an `application-test.properties` inside main/resources and create a new application.properties inside test/resources that has the `spring.profiles.active=test` line inside that references all the configuration setted on said `application-test.properties`

Comment: I already have profiles that worked fine for Flyway but for .SQL file; it is not picking up the   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema